# reading data from a JSON file into Vue application

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a json file that has a list of objects

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alkaline",
        "description": "Basic as opposed to acidic; high pH."
    },
    {
        "name": "Alkaloids",
        "description": "Water-insoluble, nitrogen containing
    }...
]
```

I need to read this file into my vuejs application and loop through all the data displaying the name and description.

The main problem I am having is actually getting access to the json.

When I do an import like

```
import json from './glossary.json';

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'...
```

I get an error saying

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The data is a static so I wont be getting it from a server and I have about 100 objects so I wanted it to be read in from another file and not hard coded in my application.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error with vue, nor json, but with javascript modules. You would need to declare the script as module when imported in your html `<script type="module" src="path/to/script.js"></script>`

But since you are using vue, go for learning single file components. It would be handled for you and you would then just

```
<script>
import yourFile from './path/to/file'
// .. you can use it here
export default {
  // .. and here
  // this is the same as the object you put into new Vue
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="el">
    <p>Your component's html goes here.</p>
    <p>It's auto mounted on the root of the template,
    so no need to even declare it above</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

[See more info on single file components on official docs here.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) (there's a nice scrimba video on top of the page as well ! )